# Access URI Parameters via webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I want to access the URI parameters of the given request:

```
http://localhost:8080/account/user?un=erik&pw=gaius
```

I can't make the following code work though,

**main.py**

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/account/user', account.User)],
                              debug=True)
```

**account.py**

```
class User(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, un, pw):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write('Yey!' + un + ' ' + pw)
```

I think there's something wrong on my main.py, but I tried to mess with it by adding named routes and regex's, but I just kept getting 500 errors (Internal Server error).

Comment: I suspect the regexp using '/account/user/<un>/<pw> only works with the URL parts, not the query part (which you wouldn't expect to be part of routing)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
class User(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    un = self.request.get('un')
    pw = self.request.get('pw')
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write('Yey!' + un + ' ' + pw)
```